# Asp.net 5 Web Application startup exception after successful publish

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, dnx50

I have an Asp.net 5 web application that works and runs fine in development (from Visual Studio or VS code I can launch no problem).  However, after successfully publishing the app, when trying to launch the website with "web.cmd" the following error appears and prevents the website from ever loading:

```js
Application startup exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'my-ng2-website' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'my-ng2-website' ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoadFile(String path, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(String path)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.LoadContext.LoadFile(String assemblyPath)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.PackageAssemblyLoader.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName, IAssemblyLoadContext loadContext)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.PackageAssemblyLoader.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.LoaderContainer.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.DefaultLoadContext.LoadAssembly(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoaderCache.GetOrAdd(AssemblyName name, Func`2 factory)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.LoadContext.LoadAssemblyImpl(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.LoadContext.ResolveAssembly(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
   at System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Startup.StartupLoader.FindStartupType(String startupAssemblyName, IList`1 diagnosticMessages)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.EnsureStartup()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.EnsureApplicationServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.BuildApplication()
```

I have searched high and low for solutions. I can't figure out what dependency I am missing. I've tried

> deleting the package.lock.json
>
> dnu restore

Here is my dnx config setting for the project:
[image]

Here is the settings for the publish:

[image]

Can anyone read these tea leaves?

Comment: publish setting changed **my-ng2-website** to **my-ng2-website-compiled**

Comment: yes that is a typo - but the real publish settings are something completely different.  i made up "my-ng2-website" for displaying here

Comment: Is the assembly getting published? Or maybe it's getting renamed when published.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the heck of it, I set the "Compile source files into Nuget Package" to false.   And now it works.

[image]

Why it works, I don't know.  But hopefully this will help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Good day. We had few encounters with this type of error. It often times points to a missing assembly (the most common one). Checking all necessary references, set to Copy Local -> true, helps most of the time. Since assemblies/references wont be included in the publish if its set to Copy Local -> false.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where do you set Copy Local -> true?  In the public profile there is a CopyLocalFilesOutputGroupDependsOn setting.

Answer (score 0):

This error has something to do with the `global.json` file located in the project directory (not the solution one). If you want to publish the project with the compile option on make sure to add it to `publishExclude` in your `project.json`

```
"publishExclude": [
  "**.user",
  "**.vspscc",
  "global.json"
],
```